# How to remove data that shows up from 'strings' on a file?

Tags: video, diff, privacy

I've downloaded a video via a website that forces a login. Thus, it knows my login.

If I run the following on it, I get results that I do not want to have:

```
 strings video.mp4 | grep "my user name"
```

It always shows up in the video, regardless of the username used. That is, if I download video1 with user1 and video2 with user2 (where video1 and video2 are the same, except for the account that accessed the video) the following commands produce output:

```
strings video1 | grep user1
strings video2 | grep user2
```

However, mixing the two a la

```
strings video2 | grep user1
```

Produces no information. In short, the website is embedding information about me in the video and I'd like to clear it (I realize there may be other information about me embedded in the video).

Is there any way to remove this information that gets output by `strings`? Or, better yet, is there any way to compare `strings video1` to `strings video2` and remove anything that differs?

Comment: I'd be skeptical of stripping your name out with `sed` or whatever since binary octets can sometimes just happen to match. Your best bet is to try to transcode the video and hope that information gets lost in the process. Alternatively, you might be able to screencast it full screen and use video editing software to sync the video and audio tracks.

Comment: @JoelDavis I'd be inclined to agree with you, except that I've tried it with three different usernames and those usernames show up only for the video they downloaded. As for the last bit, that will be a last resort

Comment: Well transcoding should strip any excess information out. Transcoding is usually a lossy process and I'd imagine meta information like your username would probably be the first thing to get lost. [A lot of utilities also more or less automate that process.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGJY3spUff8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general case, this could be difficult to do.  But you are looking at a video.  The simplest solution here would be that they placed it into a tag.

The first thing I'd do is examine the tags.  If you have it, run `mediainfo` on the file.  Do you see your username in the output?  If so, it's just in a tag.  You could grab a tag editor and manipulate the data.  EasyTAG may be an option, but I have no specific editor that I would recommend.